# coordinate outside allowed range iText exception

Tags: itext

The llx, lly , urx, ury of co-ordinates are mentioned below

1. 401.74042     747.38     406.18842     753.91815
2. 405.9332     747.38     410.3812     753.91815
3. 410.126     747.38     414.574     753.91815

I am trying to clean up the text in these locations using iText. Only text exists in these locations since I have got these co-ordinates using the renderText method of RenderListener. 
The page size is Rectangle: 595.0x842.0 (rot: 0 degrees)

I am getting a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Coordinate outside allowed range" exception only with this PDF with iText 5.5.11

I found "[Exception occur :Reason : Coordinate outside allowed range java.lang.IllegalStateException: Coordinate outside allowed range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561835/exception-occur-reason-coordinate-outside-allowed-range-java-lang-illegalstat)" and it does not seem to help. Any help would be appreciated

#### stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Coordinate outside allowed range
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.clipper.ClipperBase.rangeTest(ClipperBase.java:119)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.clipper.ClipperBase.addPath(ClipperBase.java:192)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpRegionFilter.addRect(PdfCleanUpRegionFilter.java:423)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpRegionFilter.filterFillPath(PdfCleanUpRegionFilter.java:176)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpRegionFilter.filterStrokePath(PdfCleanUpRegionFilter.java:160)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpRenderListener.filterCurrentPath(PdfCleanUpRenderListener.java:387)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpRenderListener.renderPath(PdfCleanUpRenderListener.java:224)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.paintPath(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:400)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.access$6300(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:83)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor$PaintPath.invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:1218)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpContentOperator.invoke(PdfCleanUpContentOperator.java:139)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.invokeOperator(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:310)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.processContent(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:448)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.cleanUpPage(PdfCleanUpProcessor.java:159)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.cleanUp(PdfCleanUpProcessor.java:134)
```

*([also here](https://pastebin.ca/3812841))*

#### graphics state

The graphics state at the time of the exception:

```
Page Number:  1
Horizontal scaling:1.0
Render Mode: 0
Transformation matrix: 1.0  0.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.0
Character spacing: 0.0
Font size: 0.0
Leading: 0.0
Line Cap Style: 0
Line join style: 0
Line wodth: 1.0
Miter limit: 10.0
Rise: 0.0
Word Spacing: 0.0
Color space fill: null
Color space stroke: null
Fill color: null
Font: null
Line dash pattern: null
Stroke color: null
Is knockout: true
```

*([also here](https://pastebin.ca/3812993))*

Comment: Please share the PDF in question and your pivotal code to allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: The PDF is a bank statement. Basically, I am searching the PDF for some pattern, finding the co-ordinates of text that match the pattern and using PdfCleanUpProcessor to clear the text. This works for other bank statements. Only HDFC bank statements are giving this issue. I cannot share the bank statement here.

Comment: Can you at least share the stack trace? That might give at least a chance to help.

Comment: Sure. I am so sorry that I cannot share the PDF. Here is a link with the stack trace 
http://pastebin.ca/3812841

Comment: According to the stack trace the problem appears to be related to some path in the content stream. Please share the path in question and the complete graphics state at the time it is created.

Comment: So I am using a PdfContentStreamProcessor and a custom RenderListener. I used the PdfContentStreamProcessor to get the graphics state. If that is the right way to get it, I have uploaded the graphics state here https://pastebin.ca/3812993 .

Comment: Please also share the path in question. Furthermore, the graphics state you shared looks pretty untouched, as if it was the state at the start or the end of a content stream but not at some instruction somewhere in the middle of it; are you sure you shared the graphics state current when the problematic path is used?

Comment: I just edited the contents of your pastebin data into your question text. Please also edit the question text whenever you supply substantial additional information on the issue at hand. You can edit your question using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43962116/edit) link right underneath it.

Comment: Okay. I will take care of that the next time. I am new to iText and am not sure how I can get the graphics state. Can you please provide me some resources to understand playing with existing PDFs and looking into their graphic states

Comment: *"Can you please provide me some resources to understand playing with existing PDFs and looking into their graphic states"* - that is a matter of learning by doing. You're already *using a `PdfContentStreamProcessor` and a custom `RenderListener`*, so you have the tools of trade. The only thing you did not mention is the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) which you should have read and use for reference. Now you can debug through the code and analyse the situation in which your exception occurs.

Comment: Sure. I'll go through the standard and try to fix this. Thanks :D

Comment: Well, it would be faster if you could share the PDF in question... ;)

Comment: If I could I would :P

Comment: So, I enabled breakpoints and checked why the exception occurs. In the rangeTest method, the tests are being made for values like x: -857219306468241536 (-.857*10^14) , y: 5163925828147533824 (5.16*10^18). The Pdf page size is 595*842 and my PdfCleanUpLocations does not include this value. Is this some kind of default value for some case. Rather apart from each rectangle mentioned in the PdfCleanUpLocation and the page's rectangle, on what other values is the range test applied?

Comment: The pattern I am looking for also has a transformation matrix of                                     1.0           0.0             0.0                                                                                       0.0           1.0               0.0                                                                                      0.0           827.5           1.0

Comment: It looks very weird that for a transformation matrix which merely translates by 827.5 in y direction, there are path coordinates larger than 5*10^18. The limit set by `ClipperBase.rangeTest()` is about 4.6*10^18, so it throws the exception. On the other hand I see nothing in the PDF specification that forbids this, it allows float values up to more than 3*10^38! I would assume this is a limitation of the clipping routines used by iText, a limitation that usually does not hurt because so large coordinate values hardly ever are used.

Comment: Yep. What co-ordinates are checked by the RangeTest routine anyway? Because i see that the page's bounding rectangle co-ordinates also are checked when I am not even including them in the PdfCleanUpLocations! And I find that in some cases even when the exception is thrown, the rectangles are cleaned and in some cases, a white colored rectangle covers the text, when I am specifying the color as black

Comment: *"What co-ordinates are checked by the RangeTest routine anyway?"* - coordinates of paths. According to the stack trace in your case a rectangle.

Comment: *"in some cases, a white colored rectangle covers the text, when I am specifying the color as black"* - to look into something like this, obviously you'd need to share the PDFs in question. As I seldom read about problems of such a nature,  your PDF files appear to be some special border cases...

Comment: Does this path have a reference or something. Because I observe that the checks are made for a lot of points that are not a part of rectangle.

Comment: The stack trace seems to indicate that the path in question at least contains a rectangle.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks :D