# iText7 (PdfSweep): NullPointerException on redacting text

Tags: java, itext7

I am trying to edit the text from PDF using PDFSweep 2.0.0 (JAVA). I used [this example](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/content-extraction-and-redaction/clone-removing-content/customizing-redaction-pdfsweep).

It works for most of the PDFs I have, but on some PDF files, the code throws `NullPointerException`.

Here is code sample:

```
    CompositeCleanupStrategy strategy = new CompositeCleanupStrategy();
    strategy.add(new CustomLocationExtractionStrategy("Joe"));

    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));

    // sweep
    PdfAutoSweep autoSweep = new PdfAutoSweep(strategy);
    autoSweep.cleanUp(pdf);
    pdf.close();
```

I used [this PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jw-fX5Rh7C7K9gdu4p-Ot4GbpAUKmbMX) as SRC file. Is this a bug of itext7/pdfsweep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your dependency.
I verified it against `pdfSweep 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT` and it worked perfectly.

Redacted PDF as proof
[image: redacted PDF]

Comment: It works after updating dependecy. But getting one more exception "Coordinate outside allowed range" only in [this PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_LlMFsgXbBTt8LxFmMMvuz0C2_nEMCQG) on searching any word. Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't get that error. Please update your iText dependencies as well to the latest version (snapshot  if needed). If it still goes wrong, then it's a bug.

Comment: Yes, NullPointerException resolved by updating dependencies for that PDF, but another exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Coordinate outside allowed range" is occurring for PDF(different) attached in previous comment, if i try to redact any word in it. It will be helpful if you can check this once?

Comment: Obviously, I don't get that exception, since I was able to redact the PDF.

Comment: I am asking about [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561835/exception-occur-reason-coordinate-outside-allowed-range-java-lang-illegalstat) for [PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_LlMFsgXbBTt8LxFmMMvuz0C2_nEMCQG). It would be helpful for us if you can check this for [this PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_LlMFsgXbBTt8LxFmMMvuz0C2_nEMCQG).

Comment: The error also occurs on my end, with the second PDF. I'll log a bug.

Comment: May i get to know how long will it take?